# Implement Multiple languages in Zend Framework and how to change them?

Tags: zend-framework, localization

Im on a project that requires me to translate the project to both swedish and english for the customers that the company got.

Ive made two ini file in

```
xproject/application/messages-SV.ini.php  <- Swedish
xproject/application/messages-EN.ini.php  <- English
```

And in my defines.ini.php file Ive included only the messages-SV.ini.php file with:

```
required_once('messages-SV.ini.php');
#required_once('messages-EN.ini.php');
```

Ive already added two buttons in my view for the customer to choose from either swedish thats default or english. But I dont know how to make the button send an action to the defines file and then switch to the english file and read from that instead, should I do it via cookies or should I use something else because there is alot of underpages in the diffrent tree structure so I need the language change to be permanent until the user clicks the other language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a big question...
zend framework has standard translate component [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html), which can work with ini files. then you might need to create a language indicator cookie and an action to change it. check this flag on every page load(predispatch maybe) and pass the corresponding ini file to Zend_Translate.